# Cookie not set in browser using RTK fetchBaseQuery and cors

Tags: express, cookies, cors, response, rtk-query

I have a PERN stack app and I am trying to send a cookie on login but even though it's sent within the response, it is not set in the browser.
I use RTK queries on the front side, with [`fetchBaseQuery`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery) set like this :

```
export const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
  prepareHeaders: headers => {
    headers.set(
      'Authorization',
      `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
    );
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

    return headers;
  },
  credentials: 'include',
});
```

On the backend side, I use express with cors like this :

```
app.use(cors({ origin: process.env.APP_BASE_URL, credentials: true }));
```

When I send the response, I send it like this :

```
response.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, jwtService.cookieOptions).json({
        bodyOfTheResponse,
      });
```

with cookieOptions set like this :

```
cookieOptions: {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'none',
    path: '/',
  } as CookieOptions,
```

The cookie is well received by the browser, I can see it in the `Set-Cookie` response header, but it is not stored.

Comment: Does `process.env.APP_BASE_URL` contain a path? And does `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` use `http` or `https`?

Comment: Well, process.env.APP_BASE_URL looks like `https://somesite.app` and process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL looks like `https://anothersite.com/api`

Comment: Ok, thank you. And are you getting a CORS error in your browser's console? If you do, please edit your question and add the error message there.

Comment: No, it is not a cors error, I have a status 200 response :'(

Answer (score 1):

Alright, FINALLY found the problem.
With RTK queries, I need to specify that I use cors mode, and not only specify the credentials to true.
So I needed something like this :

```
    export const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
      baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
      prepareHeaders: headers,
      credentials: 'include',
      mode: 'cors',
    });
```